# Ordering results of WP Query not working for orderby and order parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

My goal is to order posts by their name which is stored as ($category[0]->cat_name) and not by date. I understand that by default the wp_query orders them by date which is why they are currently ordered by date as stated here: [Order Parameters](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-status-order-and-pagination--cms-23167)

My code is as follows:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'pastpapers', 
            'posts_per_page' => 20000, 
            // the value of orderby doesn't change anything
            'orderby' => 'date',
            // the value of order doesn't change anything
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                 array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'category',
                     'field' => 'term_id',
                     'terms'    => $category->term_id
                 ),
            ),
        );
```

I don't think the problem is with my loop but here is the code anyways:

```
$dataQuery = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($dataQuery->have_posts()) : 
            while ($dataQuery->have_posts()) : $dataQuery->the_post();
        
                $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
                
                echo '<strong class="d-block text-secondary2 text-uppercase">'. $category[0]->cat_name .'</strong>';

            endwhile; 
        endif; 
        

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    } // End foreach
    ?>
```

I have tried changing the values of orderby and order, and completely removing them but the order of the posts on the website doesn't change. I assume that it is because it is using the default order and not whatever values I put in the arguments for orderby and order. However I don't know why it is using the default values and not my custom ones.

I have read this similar question: [orderby not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206460/wp-query-on-order-and-orderby-is-not-working)

But still don't know how to solve my issue.
I also read a similar question on stack overflow where it seemed to be an issue with a plugin overwriting the query but I don't think that is the case as I am not using that plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't order by category in a `WP_Query` like this, because a post can have many categories so there is no clear logic to decide how to order posts when they have multiple values that can have different positions in the order. Depending on what you want to do, there are different options you can try e.g. do multiple queries for different categories. If you let us know exactly what you want to do, we might be able to help come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @FluffyKitten I found an option that worked and posted it below. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that might be a bit more complicated but at least it solves my problem.

So I was trying to get the WP_query to order by title and it was ordering my posts by default value which is date and not what I wanted.

So instead I got all the posts that matched my query, put them into an array as follows:

```
$index = 0;
        
        $dataQuery = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($dataQuery->have_posts()) :
            while ($dataQuery->have_posts()) : $dataQuery->the_post();
                $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
                
                $tempLink = get_permalink();
                $tempDate = date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date));
                $tempTitle = get_the_title();
                $tempName = $category[0]->cat_name;
        
                $testArray2 = array(
                    'link' => $tempLink,
                    'date' => $tempDate,
                    'title' => $tempTitle,
                    'name' => $tempName
                );
                
                $testArray[$index++] = $testArray2;
                
            
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Once I had all the posts I wanted in my array as I wanted them I then proceeded to sort them in the order that I wanted them which was complicated as I some titles started with numbers between 1 and 20 and other posts just had titles with no numbers. At first I just used the function strcmp() but that didn't work as the numbers would be before the letters and I wanted them to be after the letters eg:
Algebra, Functions, 4. Differentiation, 10. Factorization

and not sorted like this:
4. Differentiation, 10. Factorization, Algebra, Functions

So to do that I had to first get any numbers in the title if there were any for which I used the **preg_match_all()** function and then to convert the array to a variable I used the **implode()** function

I then checked if there were not equal to 0 which would mean that it's there is a number in the string and not just a string without a number.

I sorted them by checking only one at a time with comparing i to i+1. I know that it's not the most efficient way to sort it but it works.

I created a variable **$sorts** and set it to the size of the array and decremented it each time to make sure the whole array was sorted. Not great coding but it works.

Here is the code to do that:

```
$sorts = sizeof($testArray);
        while($sorts > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i + 1 < sizeof($testArray); $i++) {
                preg_match_all('!\d+!', $testArray[$i]['name'], $matches);
                preg_match_all('!\d+!', $testArray[$i+1]['name'], $matches2);
                $var1 = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
                $var2 = implode(' ', $matches2[0]);

                if($var1 != 0 && $var2 != 0) {
                    if($var1 > $var2) {
                        $temp = $testArray[$i];
                        $testArray[$i] = $testArray[$i+1];
                        $testArray[$i+1] = $temp;
                    }
                }
                else if(($var1 != 0 && $var2 == 0)) {
                    $temp = $testArray[$i];
                    $testArray[$i] = $testArray[$i+1];
                    $testArray[$i+1] = $temp;
                }
                else if(($var1 == 0 && $var2 != 0)) {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else if(strcmp($testArray[$i]['name'], $testArray[$i+1]['name']) > 0) {
                    $temp = $testArray[$i];
                    $testArray[$i] = $testArray[$i+1];
                    $testArray[$i+1] = $temp;
                }
            }
            $sorts--;
        }
```

Once I had the sorted posts like I wanted them all I needed to do was a simple for loop and echo the posts like I wanted:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($testArray); $i++) {
  //echo code
}
```

And there we go that works.